# Repository findIn confusion

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My database has an Exchanges class which contains a list of CurrencyPairs.

Is it possible to use to use a Repository method to directly obtain a CurrencyPair which matches on name within a given Exchange?  I'm thinking of something like

```
CurrencyPairDbo findByExchangeNameAndCurrencyPairIn(...)
```

but I can't see quite how to tie it all together.  Or do I need to write a custom query for this? And does this need to be in the ExchangeRepository or the CurrencyPairRespository?

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Exchanges")  
public class ExchangeDbo {
  @Id @GeneratedValue   
  @Getter private Long id; 

  @Getter private String exchangeName;   

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exchange", 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true, 
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @BatchSize(size=100)
  @Getter private List<CurrencyPairDbo> listCurrencyPair = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}



@Entity() 
public class CurrencyPairDbo {
  @Id @GeneratedValue   
  @Getter private Long id;

  @Column(unique=true)
  private String currencyPair;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
  @Getter private ExchangeDbo exchange;
  ...
}
```

**Edit:**

I'm thinking it's not Find...In that I want at all.  I think that something like:

```
List<CurrencyPairDbo> x = exchangeRepository.findByExchangeNameLowercaseAndListCurrencyPairCurrencyPair(exchangeName.toLowerCase(), currencyPair);
```

might work, except that in returns an Exchange object and a:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [biz.ianw.coindatabase.database.ExchangeDbo] to type [biz.ianw.coindatabase.database.CurrencyPairDbo]

Answer (score 0):

This, in the currency pair repository, seems to do the job.

I added a lower case field for matching purposes and an index for efficiency.

```
CurrencyPairDbo findByExchangeExchangeNameLowercaseAndCurrencyPairNameLowercase( String exchangeName, String currencyPair );
```